# Why mt_rand generating same number repeatedly?

Tags: php, random

I have a simple code:   mt_rand(1,25);

it is generating the same number over and over. MANY times before it will finally generate a new number.

6 months ago, it worked beautifully.

```
    $X = mt_rand(1,25) ;
     $AR=array(14, 126, 28, .......);
     $F = $AR[$X];
```

Then the $F is used in a math calculation...

The $X value is the one remaining the same on every page refresh or revisit.

See in action @ Www.math-flashcards.com

Select "Numbers Plus 9" on second row of buttons. Input a name and then the code should be generating different flashcards each time.

Comment: the same number could be generated an infinite-1 times, and still be complete randomly chosen

Comment: any how, you need to show how your actually using it, because thats the problem, not the function

Comment: Are you calling `mt_srand` at all? This is used to initialize the `seed`. You should not be calling it unless your want the same sequence of numbers.

Comment: let me guess, you're using an ancient (5.2.X?) version of PHP? upgrade to 5.4 or higher, and i think you'll be safe..  -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php changelog

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only calling `mt_rand()` a single time.  If you are using this in a loop, please include the other statements in the loop.

Possible pitfalls:

- You are calling mt_srand() elsewhere in the loop, which is resetting the random state for each time through the loop.
- You are comparing successive executions of the script itself, and you have a PHP version that is out of date (all still-supported PHP versions initially seel the random state with a random value upon script execution).